# Carrierwave, UpLoader no carga en el model en rails ni en rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Resulta que estoy utilizando la *gem CarrierWave* en un proyecto en *rails*. La cosa es que al cargar el *uploader* en el atributo del *model Curriculum* obtengo el siguiente error:

> 2.4.1 :002 > Curriculum.new
>   NameError: uninitialized constant Curriculum::CvUploader
>   from app/models/curriculum.rb:2:in  `<class:Curriculum>`
>   from app/models/curriculum.rb:1:in `<main>`
>   from (irb):2

El model es el siguiente:

```
class Curriculum < ApplicationRecord
    mount_uploader :archivo, CvUploader
end
```

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que no cargaba debido a que en el *gemfile* no se cargaba la *gem CarrierWave*, así que la puse más arriba en el *gemfile* cambiando su posición más arriba.

Eso era todo, cargar bien *la gema*.